# Angular - Mostrar y ocultar componentes

Tags: angular, typescript, formularios, frontend

Tengo los siguientes componentes HTML:

```
   <app-header></app-header>
   <app-modal-login></app-modal-login>
```

Dentro del componente app-header, hay otro componente HTML: , con el siguiente botón:

```
<button id="BotonAbrirLogin">Click</button>
```

Inicialmente el componente <app-modal-login debe estar oculto y si hago click en el BotonAbrirLogin deberia mostrarse el componente en cuestion.

¿Como puedo resolverlo? Ya he intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
<app-modal-login *ngIf="is0n"></app-modal-login>
<button id="BotonAbrirLogin" (click)="is0n = false"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

como el componente inicialmente debe estar oculto, entonces en el typescript del componente debe inicializar la variable con un valor falso:

```
is0n = false;
```

y cuando hace click debe cambiar la variable a verdadero para que se muestre el componente:

```
<app-modal-login *ngIf="is0n"></app-modal-login>
<button id="BotonAbrirLogin" (click)="is0n = true"></button>
```